# How to I selectively merge two text files using R?

Tags: r

So I have 2 text files.  The actual files are very large (thousands of lines each) but this is an extract from them:

File 1:

```
L["Corn Flakes"] = ""
L["Rice Oats"] = ""
L["Shreddies"] = ""
```

File 2:

```
L["Marshmellows"] = "Tesco"
L["Golden Syrup"] = "Morrisons"
L["Corn Flakes"] = "Tesco"
L["Bran Flakes"] = "Asda"
L["Super Flakes"] = "Asda"
L["Rice Oats"] = "Asda"
L["Shreddies"] = "Morrisons"
L["Rice Krispies"] = "Tesco"
```

So I want to merge these files so that I end up with this in a new text file:

Merged file:

```
L["Corn Flakes"] = "Tesco"
L["Rice Oats"] = "Asda"
L["Shreddies"] = "Morrisons"
```

In other words, I want to merge file 1 and file 2 but the merged file should only contain the rows that are in file 1 but the actual rows in the merged file should be from file 2.

The merged file should be output to a new, empty text file and it needs to be in UTF-8 format so that it works in any language.  All the files (file 1, file  and the merged file) need to be standard .txt files.

How can I do this in R?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most SO users are happy to help you solve problems with your code, but are less willing to write your code for you.

Comment: I know how to merge files by a specific column but that is where the files contain columns.  I don't know how to merge files selectively where there are no columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the two files with `'='` as separator so you have files with two columns. Keep rows in `file2` which has the first column (`V1`) present in `file1`. Write the `result` back to a new text file if needed.

```
file1 <- read.table('file1.txt', sep = '=', quote = '')
file2 <- read.table('file2.txt', sep = '=', quote = '')

result <- file2[file2$V1 %in% file1$V1, ]
```

---

To include all the rows in `file1` irrespective if they are present in `file2` you may try the join approach.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(file1 %>% select(-any_of('V2')), file2, by = 'V1') %>%
    bind_rows(anti_join(file1, file2, by = 'V1')) %>%
    data.frame() -> result
```

Write the result :

```
write.table(result, 'result.txt', sep = '=', col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: This looks very promising.  The output file contains this though: "75"="L[Corn Flakes] "="Tesco"
"84"="L[Bran Flakes] "="Asda"
The characters before the L[ at the beginning of each line shouldn't be there.  Also, how can I remove all lines beginning with -- from file 1 before the merge (I need to remove all lines from file 1 which start with double-hyphen, but only if the double-hyphen is at the beginning of the line)?

Comment: I solved most of the prefix characters problem with this: row.names = F, but now the result is like this: "L[Corn Flakes] "="Tesco" - The extra quotes shouldn't be there.  How to fix the quotes?

Comment: To be clear, the results file should contain this: L["Corn Flakes"] = "Tesco" but instead it contains this: "L[Corn Flakes] "=" Tesco"

Comment: That doesn't work because it removes all quotes.  So with your updated code, results is like this: L[Corn Flakes] = Tesco but I need it to be like this L["Corn Flakes"] = "Tesco".  I need the quotes to be merged in-tact as they are in both file1 and file2.

Comment: structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("L[Corn Flakes] ", 
"L[Rice Krispies] ", "L[Shreddies] "), class = "factor"), V2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: That's perfect, Ronak, thank you.  Before I mark it, can you tell me one little thing - sometimes the source file (file1) contains rows prefixed with -- (double hyphen) - I want to discard these rows from file1 before the files are merged.  How do I discard all lines in file1 that start with -- before the files are merged?

Comment: Ah there is a problem with the code.  If file1 contains a row that doesn't exist at all in file2, the row is not included in result.  I need everything in file1 to be included in result even if it doesn't exist in file2.  So if file1 contains L["Nothing"] = "" but L["Nothing"] doesn't exist in file2, I still need L["Nothing"] = "" to be included in result.  At present, it's omitted from result.

Comment: I got it working almost perfectly with your first answer (using result <- file2[file2$V1 %in% file1$V1, ]).  Just one small thing that doesn't work - if a row in file1 is identical to a row in file2, I don't want it to be included in result.  So if file1 contains L["Shreddies"] = "Tesco" and file2 contains L["Shreddies"] = "Tesco" (the exact same line), I don't want it to be included in result. 
 How can I do that?

Comment: You're right.  I asked a new question for the duplicate problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67285316/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-r