# How do I remove duplicates in R?

Tags: r

So I have file1.txt:

```
L["Corn Flakes"] = ""
L["Rice Oats"] = ""
L["Shreddies"] = ""
```

and file2.txt:

```
L["Marshmellows"] = "Tesco"
L["Golden Syrup"] = "Morrisons"
L["Corn Flakes"] = "Tesco"
L["Bran Flakes"] = "Asda"
L["Super Flakes"] = "Asda"
L["Rice Oats"] = "Asda"
L["Shreddies"] = "Morrisons"
L["Rice Krispies"] = "Tesco"
```

So I have this script which merges file2 into file1 but only for rows that exist in file1.

```
# Read file1
file1 <- read.table('file1.txt', sep = '=', quote = '', fill = TRUE)

# Remove commented out rows from file1
file1 <- file1[!grepl('--', file1$V1), ]

# Remove line that contains {}
file1 <- file1[!grepl('\\{\\}', file1$V2), ]

# Read file2
file2 <- read.table('file2.txt', sep = '=', quote = '', fill = TRUE)

# Remove rows from file2 if they are incomplete
file2 <- file2[!grepl('""', file2$V2),]

# Merge file1 and file2 into result but only including rows that are complete
result <- file2[file2$V1 %in% file1$V1, ]

# Write to file
write.table(result, 'result.txt', sep = '=', col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

The script works fine except for one small thing.  I don't want result to include rows that are identical in file1 and file2.  So if file1 contains L["Shreddies"] = "Tescos" and file2 contains L["Shreddies"] = "Tescos", I don't want L["Shreddies"] = "Tescos" to be included in result.  How do I do this?

Comment: `library(dplyr); result <- anti_join(result, file1, by = c("col1" = "col1", "col2" = "col2")` where col1 and col2 are your column names. How did your data get into this horrible state, btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, after you run your existing code up to `result` and before `write.table`:

```
result <- unique(result)
```

EDIT after better understanding problem. I think this should do it:

```
result <- file2[(file2$V1 %in% file1$V1) &
                !(file2[c("V1", "V2")] %in% file1[c("V1","V2")]),]
```

One more EDIT:

```
result <- file2[(file2$V1 %in% file1$V1),]

library(dplyr)

result <- result %>% 
            anti_join(file1, by = c("V1", "V2"))
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I added L["test1"] = "test1"
to file1 and L["test1"] = "test1" to file2 but it still appeared in result.  I added your line just before write.table.  I'm unsure how that could work.  I don't want lines that exist exactly in file1 and file2 to be included in result but at the time your line is run, result only contains unique lines so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: This line result <- file2[file2$V1 %in% file1$V1, ] merges file1 and file2 but only includes rows that exist in file1, is it possible to change this line so it merges the same way but also excludes rows that exactly exist in file1 and file2?

Comment: @Jstation see my edit in the original post and see if that works! Apologies for not initially understanding your problem and how you combined the files.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I see rows in file1 that exist exactly in file2 but they are still included in result.  Also, when I run the code, I see this error: In (file2$V1 %in% file1$V1) & !(file2[c("V1", "V2")] %in% file1[c("V1",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I fixed the error.  File2 contained a row that didn't have 2 columns.  So that's fixed the error.  But still, rows that exist exactly in file1 and file2 are still shown in result.

Comment: Gah, one last edit. I just tested and this should definitely work. It uses the dplyr::anti_join() function, which you would pass your initial `result` dataframe into.

Comment: No problem! Took a few tries but we got there, haha.